# sarama.ConsumePartition instances is sharing default group or using different group?

Tags: go, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

When I using sarama.ConsumePartition for same topic and same partition in different process, is the behavior like they sharing an default group or like they are using unique group?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `ConsumePartition` you HAVE to give the offset to start consuming (along with topic and partition). And it will start to consume from that given offset.

There will be no sharing of messages/partitions like group consumers.